# How to solve undefined local variable or method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three tables: `RM`, `GenericUser`, `Properties`.

`RM` fields: `id`, `name`

`GenericUser` fields: `id`, `mobile`, `rm_id`, `name`.

`Properties` fields `id`, `image`, `rm_id`, `generic_user_id`, `property_name`.

`RM` is creating `GenericUser`, so that `rm_id` is automatically entered in `GenericUser` table.

After that generic user logs in and creates property, so when generic user creates property, `rm_id` should fetch from generic user table and should enter in property table field where `rm_id` is.

I have model relation like this.

```
class Rm < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :user
    has_many :generic_users
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :generic_user
end

class GenericUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rm
    has_many :properties
end
```

My generic_users `propertiescontroller`:

```
def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    @gu=GenericUser.select(:rm_id).where(:id=>current_user.specific.id)
    @property.rm_id=@gu.rm_id
   logger.info @gu.inspect
    logger.info @property.rm_id.inspect
    if @property.save
        redirect_to  :back, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' 
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

when i inspect @gu 
iam getting this

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<GenericUser id: 1, mobile: "8776766777", address: "reewtrwt", created_at: "2016-02-18 07:41:06", updated_at: "2016-02-19 08:59:13", dob: "", rm_id: "4", category_id: "1",>]>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)`

how i will save this GenericUser rm_id(ie; rm_id :4) to properties table field rm_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in these lines:

```
@gu = GenericUser.select(:rm_id).where(:id=>current_user.specific.id)
@property.rm_id = @gu.rm_id
```

Explanation:

`@gu` was returned as `Active Record Relations`, so you couldn't call `@gu.rm_id`

**Solution** - Try something like this:

```
@gu = GenericUser.find(current_user.specific.id)
@property.rm_id = @gu.rm_id
```

`@gu` is now a `GenericUser`, so you can call `rm_id` on it

Answer (score 0):

You've already selected rm_id in @gu. You don't need to call it again.

Change this,

```
@property.rm_id=@gu.rm_id
```

To this,

```
 @property.rm_id = @gu
```

Comment: it is inserting as null